# Why IntelliJ marked my class as J?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Can someone explain to me why IntelliJ decided to mark some of my classes with  [image] symbol?

I have multiple classes in the same package and some are marked with [image] whereas others with [image].

I wouldn't not mind if [image] didn't cause the class to lose colouring and more importantly shortcuts stopped working(!), for example `Find usages ALT+F7`.

[image]

*.iml configuration file:

```
<content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/java" isTestSource="true" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target" />
</content>
```

Note this was working correctly before (yesterday). Just happened today. The maven project builds correctly. The classes are correct.

Answer (score 4):

Files marked with [image] are java source files presents in a directory marked a source root (or a subdirectory of it) from intelliJ.

Files marked with [image] are java source files presents in a directory that is NOT marked as source root (or a sub directory of it) from IntelliJ.

Generally circle icons are related to file in directory recognized from IntelliJ as source, squares are files not in a source directory.

For a complete description of each icon you can see the following links:

- [Symbols](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/symbols.html) - Here you can find the [image] icon
- [File Types](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/file-types-recognized-by-intellij-idea.html) - Here you can find the [image] icon

If a file is not under a directory tree marked as source root it is only a file.

Instead if a file is under a directory tree marked as source root it is recognized as a class, annotation, interface, or enum and it is visible with the command `Find Usages ALT+F7`, because is part of the source.

---

Additional note. If a file has extension java, but is not a java class (for example if the file is empty) the icon is [image] also if present in a tree marked as source tree, because IntelliJ can't understand if it is a class, an enum, an interface or something different.

So check the content of the files marked as [image]. It is possible that for example the declaration of the class is wrong written.

For example a file MyClass.java with this content

```
public clas MyClass {
}
```

has the icon [image] because the declaration of the class is wrong.

Correcting to the following change also the icon to [image]

```
// Added an s to class
public class MyClass {
}
```

Comment: I posted the package tree and java directory is marked as the source folder. They are present in the same directory with the class file but yet is marked as J.

Comment: I see. Try to close and reopen IntelliJ to see if it works.

Comment: I made a test on my IntelliJ and I updated the answer to show you when it happens.

Comment: If simply restart does not help, try "File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart"

Comment: See the additional note in the answer. Your file doesn't contain a valid java code. The internal interpreter of IntelliJ can't understand if it is a class, an enum, an interface, an annotation...

Answer (score 0):

Directory under which resides your java files is not source code directory.

You can mark directory in Intellij.

It is described here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/configuring-content-roots.html

You can also right click on directory and use mark directory as.

If You using maven project, You should follow maven pattern of directories

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you accidentally turned on Power Save (File/Power Save Mode) I myself just discovered that File/Power Save Mode does turn it off. I was having the same problem and must have accidentally set Power Save Mode to on.